# Headphone hiss after upgrade to 14.10

Tags: sound, 14.10

I upgraded from 13.10 to 14.10 and now I get a hissing sound on the left side whenever I use headphones (tried different headphones). The problem was not present (or at least not at a noticeable level) before, and now it is really strong. Also, it still works well under Windows, so I'm assuming it's a software problem.
My Notebook is a Lenovo T440p.

```
aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC3232 Analog [ALC3232 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

dpkg -l | grep alsa
ii  alsa-base                                            1.0.25+dfsg-0ubuntu4                     all          ALSA driver configuration files
ii  alsa-utils                                           1.0.28-1ubuntu1                          amd64        Utilities for configuring and using ALSA
ii  bluez-alsa:amd64                                     4.101-0ubuntu20                          amd64        Bluetooth ALSA support
ii  gstreamer0.10-alsa:amd64                             0.10.36-2                                amd64        GStreamer plugin for ALSA
ii  gstreamer1.0-alsa:amd64                              1.4.3-1ubuntu1                           amd64        GStreamer plugin for ALSA


dpkg -l | grep pulseaudio
ii  gstreamer0.10-pulseaudio:amd64                       0.10.31-3+nmu1ubuntu5                    amd64        GStreamer plugin for PulseAudio
ii  gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio:amd64                        1.4.3-1ubuntu1                           amd64        GStreamer plugin for PulseAudio
ii  pulseaudio                                           1:4.0-0ubuntu22                          amd64        PulseAudio sound server
ii  pulseaudio-module-bluetooth                          1:4.0-0ubuntu22                          amd64        Bluetooth module for PulseAudio sound server
ii  pulseaudio-module-x11                                1:4.0-0ubuntu22                          amd64        X11 module for PulseAudio sound server
ii  pulseaudio-utils
```

Link to the alsa-info.sh output: http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=6321ee0e6a40fc13b0b0191969f190c5434d0ed1

Comment: Do you get the hiss on the notebook speakers or just on the headphones? It won't solve anything, but installing alsamixer and running it from the command line will allow you to look at and change all your audio levels which may help to isolate where the noise is coming from.

Comment: It's on the headphones only. I did try the alsamixer, but it seems the only time the noise turns off is when sound to the headphones is completely off.

Comment: in alsamixer, press F6 and select the last sound card, then F5 to display all controls :  try to tweak faders and settings, especially toggle "loopback" switch , and mute or lower "capture" switchs and "digital" /"iec958"/"spdif" switch. There is a small chance that alsa-info give some tip: Run this command in a terminal:
`wget http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-info.sh -O alsa-info.sh && bash alsa-info.sh`
Choose the upload option and provide a link for the output.

Comment: @laugeo I can modify capture, but it doesn't change anything. Loopback, however, is not in there. I added the link as suggested.

Comment: Hiss is spdif. Try to disable spdif in alsamixer with space...

Comment: @iugamarian i can turn off spdif with M (mute) only. however that doesn't change anything.

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue? 14.10 is EOL, so if you're still using Ubuntu, I guess (hope!) that you're using a supported version... Do you still have the problem?

Comment: The issue is still there on 17.10, but I don't care much about it since it doesn't appear when I drive the headphones through a docking station, which is almost always for me.